# How to config Webpack and Babel to use ES5 and ES6 in one project

Tags: webpack, babeljs

How do I configure Babel and Webpack to load ES6 source code and ES5 vendor library, e.g.: jQuery, and our old lib javascript files in one project? They all have the same *.js extension.

```
  {
    test: /\.js$/,
    loader: 'babel',
    include: projectRoot,
    exclude: /node_modules/
  },
```

Above loader will load ES6 correctly, but treat all js file as ES6. What about my old lib js files that are in ES5?

Here are my .babelrc file:

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "stage-2"],
  "plugins": ["transform-runtime"],
  "comments": false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

ES6 is backwards compatible with ES5. You shouldn't need to worry about this. ES5 code will not be transpiled and presumably will be copied verbatim (perhaps with some optimisation though I am not sure)